# How to generate ROC curve for decision tree?

Tags: matlab, roc

I have implemented a decision tree, I wish to evaluate it by ROC curve.

However, I have no idea how to define the threshold for it. As far as I known, the performance of a decision tree can be represented by a single confusion matrix, so it should correspond to a single point in the ROC graph. How should I make a curve?

Thanks!

Comment: Can you post what you have done so far?

Comment: If your decision tree doesn't have a parameter with which to regulate a trade-off between false positives and false negatives, then an ROC curve simply doesn't make any sense.

Comment: @A.Donda this should be an answer, and the accepted one, instead of a comment.

Comment: see this link for answer http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/105760/how-we-can-draw-an-roc-curve-for-decision-trees